# Calling Bash script from Java changing arguments

Tags: java, bash, shell

Directly from terminal, I can call
    `sh script.sh "test ing" 1 2`
works fine -- there are 3 arguments: test ing, 1, 2

Calling the exact same thing from java with
    `Process call = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh script.sh \"test ing\" 1 2")`
has 4 arguments: "test, ing", 1, 2

To clarify, I can remove the quotes and calling the both cases have the same behavior as calling from java. How can I call this script from java to work with my desired behavior of its arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also try with:

```
Process call = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"sh", "script.sh", "test ing", "1", "2"});
```

This way allows you to have more control on the arguments you pass.

Comment: This worked! I'm a big fan of that syntax for the control you get of each parameter